# Django - taking values from POST request, JavaScript fetch API

Tags: python, django, django-forms, fetch-api, django-3.0

Sorry if this is a noob question, I am  creating a **Django app** and for that I am trying to access data received from POST request, using JavaScript fetch API but it is showing empty .
I can't get what my mistake is.
I have tried to remove all unnecessary parts to debug.The error is in this part:

Code of my `views.py`

```
def checkdb(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = request.POST.get('tag', 'default')
        print("printing", a)
        print(request.POST)
    return HttpResponse("Hello")

def check(request):
    return render(request, 'shop/new.html')
```

Code of `URLS.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="shop"),
    path('checkdb/', views.checkdb, name="checkdb"),
    path('check/', views.check, name="check"),
]
```

Code of `new.html`, it has only script tag to fetch request just for testing purpose.

```
<script>

data = JSON.stringify({
    headline: "Testing",
    tag: "Testing",
    background_image: "Testing",
    content: "Testing",
    user: 1
})

let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
let response = fetch("/shop/checkdb/", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
})


function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

</script>
```

When i go to endpoint *shop/check*  then its script tag executes and there is no error in console but when i try to print the data received in terminal then it always prints default option i am not getting what is mistake I want to print the data corresponding to key "tag" which is "Testing" but it is giving default option Please help me to find out my mistake.

OUTPUT in terminal

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[01/May/2020 19:09:02] "GET /shop/check/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1091
printing default
<QueryDict: {}>
[01/May/2020 19:09:02] "POST /shop/checkdb/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5
```

I am using Django 3.0.4.

Thanks and sorry if there is any silly mistake, i am a newbie in Django

Comment: This worked for me; you are a hero

Answer (score 20):

In my experience, data sent using fetch are not located inside `request.POST` but rather inside `request.body`. There are then cases where the received data is in byte so you will need to decode it first. I suggest that you do this first:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    import json
    post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

Then try accessing `post_data` content like a normal python dictionary to get the value of `tag` as in `post_data.get("tag")`

Answer (score 3):

As per my research request.POST won't work it only works when there is form data, i solved my issue of accessing the data by using

```
 data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
 tag = data['tag']
 print(data)
 print(tag)
```

And to use json.loads() first you have to `import json` module.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

> `json.loads()` Deserialize s (a str, bytes or bytearray instance
> containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion
> table.

The data inside `request.body` is of `bytes` type. As `json.loads` already accepts `bytes` type of data, we do not need to `decode` it. So, we can simply write:

```
data = json.loads(request.data)
print(data) # We get data as a dictionary
```

Answer (score -1):

The view received the data from the AJAX POST request and the data was in the JSON format, so we need to load it using the `json` module from the standard library:

```
import json

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get the data from the ajax post request
        data = json.load(request) # dictionary
        tag = data.get('tag')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to mention, in my experience:

```
import json


def some_view(request):
    # data = request.POST  # Is going to work for the test client
    data = json.loads(request.body)  # Works, but for the test client it doesn't
```